# asp:GridView style not chaning in IE

Tags: asp.net, css, gridview

I put a gridview on a page and used one of the default styles that VS 2008 comes with.  I used brown sugar and then changed the values for the backcolor, forecolor, etc, but when I run it in IE, it still takes on the Brown Sugar appearance.  When I run it in firefox, it is applying the styles I gave it.

Comment: Why does IE have to be so troublesome and difficult?

Comment: That is the exact question I am trying to answer.

Comment: You can try to see if your IE7 is ignoring styles or colors. http://www.microsoft.com/enable/training/windowsvista/webaccessibility.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try clearing cache of IE

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried to do to remedy this situation?

Two things I would try:

1. Refresh cached styles in the browser (SHIFT+Reload)
2. [Restart IIS](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/003ed2fe-6339-4919-b577-6aa965994a9b.mspx?mfr=true) with `iisreset /noforce computername` from command line.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the cache.  In IE 7 it is ctrl-f5 (not shift-f5 as someone else mentioned).

> Refresh page and the cache     CTRL+F5

http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/attachment/715071.ashx

Answer (score 0):

this seems to be a real issue with asp.net and IE? i tried also the autoformat on gridview Firefox gets it but IE (version IE8)!